# Regex rules for optional url parameter

Tags: regex

How to write the regrex rules for the specific given url parameter?

For exmaple, I have URL below:

1. `http://localhost:5008/api/products/productsSubscribeStatus?companyId=14`
2. `http://localhost:5008/api/products/productsSubscribeStatus`
3. `http://localhost:5008/api/products/productsSubscribeStatus?ccc=14`

I want to a rule only match "products/productsSubscribeStatus" and only with the parameter "companyID=xx", but does not pass the url with the other parameters like the third one.

I write the regrex: `\/products\/productsSubscribeStatus(\?companyId=\d+$)?`, but it cannot guarantee the parameter is `companyId` only.

Comment: Is no query parameter also acceptable?

Comment: Yes, on my example, I want the url 1 and 2 pass, but not the third one. Only allow the url without parameter or parameter with ```companyId``` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just make the entire expected query parameter optional:

```
^https?://.+/products/productsSubscribeStatus(?:\?companyId=\w+)?$
```

### Demo